# Idiomatic way of expressing no where mentioned

Tags: idiomatic-language

Are there any idiomatic ways of expressing no where mentioned in a sentence.

Sentence:

> The paragraph so quoted was **no where mentioned** in the actual text

Comment: You can use the word **not**. *The paragraph quoted was not in the actual text.*

Comment: Also, you may use the word "nowhere" and not two words "no where".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The paragraph quoted was absent from the actual text.
- The paragraph quoted was nowhere to be found in the actual text.
- The paragraph quoted was missing from the actual text.
- The paragraph quoted was conspicuously absent from the actual text. [sarcastic]